# Using Boost.Spirit.Qi with custom lexer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I dug through the whole [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) and couldn't find an example. All the examples either parse character data or use Spirit.Lex. Forgive me if I missed something.

Can someone give an example for, or point to a tutorial on, how to use Boost.Spirit.Qi with my custom lexer? E.g.:

```
vector<MyTokenType> tokens = GetTokens();
// use boost spirit to work with MyTokenType on per-token granularity
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do sevaral things:

a) expose the token sequence as a range of iterators, which will have to be passed to parse/phrase_parse
b) add a default conversion operator to your token type exposing the token id

```
struct token
{
    operator int() const { return id; }
};
```

that allows to use `qi::char_(ID)` as a parser component matching a token with the token id `ID`.

Integrating attributes (token values) is more involved, look at Spirit.Lex how it can be done.